# XPages error -- dojo/parser::parse() error TypeError: s.match is not a function

Tags: dojo, xpages

I am getting the following error in the browser console for only one page in my application (there are hundreds of pages, but only the one is throwing this console error)

```
dojo/parser::parse() error TypeError: s.match is not a function

at _148.xe_ecn [as extractCN] (/xsp/.ibmxspres/.extlib/dijit/ExtLib.js:32)

at Object._extractLabel (/xsp/.ibmxspres/.extlib/dijit/NameTextBox.js:25)

at Object._createChoiceItem (/xsp/.ibmxspres/.extlib/dijit/_ListTextBox.js:59)

at Object._setValueAttr (/xsp/.ibmxspres/.extlib/dijit/_ListTextBox.js:51)

at Object.$DDDR_ [as set] (xspClientDojoUI.js:5)

at Object.$DDDE_ [as _applyAttributes] (xspClientDojoUI.js:5)

at Object._276 (dojo.js:15)

at Object.$DDCr_ [as _applyAttributes] (xspClientDojoUI.js:5)

at Object.$DDDD_ [as create] (xspClientDojoUI.js:5)

at Object._276 (dojo.js:15)
```

I discovered this as an xe:tooltip was no longer working, when it was working fine before.

Any ideas/clues as to what might trigger this error?

Answer (score 0):

The difference for the page throwing the error is I was loading the following resource in an attempt to disable the Chrome autofill "feature" :

```
 jquery.disableAutoFill.min.js
```

When I dropped the line to load the above my error went away